# Delimiter matching in c++ - segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I keep getting the segmentation fault error when running my program. I have no clue what is wrong. I googled the error message, I just don't know what it means. Any help would be great!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool delimiterMatching(char *file){
  stack<char> x;
  int count = 0;
  char ch, onTop, check;
  while(ch != '/n'){
    ch = file[count];
    if (ch == '(' || '[' || '{')
      x.push(ch);

    else if (ch == ')' || ']' || '}') {
      onTop == x.top();
      x.pop();
      if((ch==')' && onTop!='(') || (ch==']' && onTop!='[') || (ch=='}' &&
                                onTop!= '{'))
    return false;        
    }

  count++;
  }

  if (x.empty())
    return true;
  else 
    return false;

}


int main()
{
  char test[50];
  cout << "enter sentence: ";
  cin >> test;

    if (delimiterMatching(test))
    cout << "success" << endl;
  else 
    cout << "error" << endl;

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\n` instead of `/n`? Also, look at the conditions in your first `if-else` block. They look quite wrong.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: `if (ch == a || b)` does not mean "if ch is equal to a or b", it means "if ch is equal to a, or b is not 0".

Answer (score 2):

A segmentation fault means your program tried to access a memory address that isn't valid.  Typically it means you dereferenced a dangling pointer or indexed past the end of an array.

In this case, it looks like the problem is your `while(ch != '/n')` line.  It has two problems:

- First, `'/n'` is not a valid character literal.  You probably meant `'\n'`, which represents a newline character.
- Second, your string doesn't end with a newline character, because `cin >> test` reads one line and discards the newline at the end.  Your loop will go past the end of the array and into whatever's after it in memory, trying to find a newline character, and eventually it'll reach a location that it can't access, causing a segmentation fault.  You should be checking for `'\0'`, which is the null character that *actually* marks the end of the string.

When I change the `ch != '/n'` to `ch != '\0'`, the program doesn't crash.

It'd be easier and safer to use a `std::string` rather than a `char[50]`, by the way.

Comment: how do you use std::string? When I do that it says can't convert from string to char*. Sorry for such basic questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use such comparison

```
    if (ch == '(' || '[' || '{')
```

Try

```
    if (ch == '('  || ch== '[' || ch=='{')
```